# Upgraded to Display Suite 7.x-2.8 and my Node Titles Are Missing

Tags: 7, display-suite, nodes

I just updated to 7.x-2.8 and now all of the Titles of my Node Teasers are missing. Example: http://liberalgeek.com/

Each of the boxes on that page should have the title as the first item in the box (above the image).

[image]

When I go to Manage Display, the Title field is entirely missing from the available options.

[image]